# Script won't stop itself

Tags: javascript, node.js, github, github-actions

I have two scripts, let's call them "first" and "second".

I have no issue with "first" script, here how it's looks:

```
  const fetch = require('node-fetch');

  console.log(typeof fetch); // prints: function

  fetch(URLHERE)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => {

      console.log(res);

    });
```

And here is a "second" script which won't stop itself after it's run

```
  const APIWRAPPER = require('APIWRAPPER');
  const api = new APIWRAPPER(TOKEN);

  console.log(typeof api); // prints: object

  api.find(QUERY)
    .then(json => {

      console.log(json);

    });
```

Both scripts outputs same thing.

But when I running "second" script it won't stop. I have to press Ctrl + C in my win terminal.

And you might ask, is it such a big issue for me to press Ctrl + C once in a while? No it's not, but I'm trying to trigger this script with GitHub Action and it's just endlessly running leaving me one option: cancel it.

P.S. I'm using `node run first` and `node run second` to trigger those scripts.

package.json:

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "first": "node ./scripts/first.js",
    "second": "node ./scripts/second.js"
  },
}
```

What I tried:

```
  const APIWRAPPER = require('APIWRAPPER');
  const api = new APIWRAPPER(TOKEN);

  console.log(typeof api); // prints: object

  api.find(QUERY)
    .then(json => {

      console.log(json);

      process.exit(0); // Adding this

    });
```

But I'm not sure if it's good practice, it was just first thing I found.

Comment: you seem to be trying to truncate what you share but the rest of your code could be helpful here.  also, `node run first` will try to run `node run.js` with an arg of `first`

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your scripts but I know that you can auto cancel your pipeline by setting a specific timeout by default :

`job.<id>.timeout-minutes` sets a timeout for a whole job

`job.<id>.steps.timeout-minutes` sets a timeout for a single step

Your scenario:

```
my-job:
 runs-on:  ubuntu-latest
 timeout-minutes: 30
```

Comment: already set it to 10 mins, just so I don't have to cancel it myself while testing, doesn't solve my issue :(

Comment: Well, it's weird but do you have tried to set a timeout or an interval in your script?

Comment: oh, sorry wasn't clear with my response, I added timeout after asking this question, but it's doesn't really solve my question.

Answer (score 0):

If the script doesn't stop, it means that your `APIWRAPPER` still does something, like have connections to the api open (websockets, token refresh logic, etc).

So you should look if the `APIWRAPPER` has some kind of `stop`/`shutdown` mechanism.

**Edit:**

`process.exit(0);` Should be avoided, because you might kill "something" during an operation.